# Update order items with box quantity

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am trying to update a shipping database that is set-up incorrectly from the start with table structure, but am having to work with it (for now).

What I need is for example with the DDL below there were `3` total shipments for the `saleId`- what I need to have the query do is:

```
Create Table Testing
(
  saleId int
  ,totalQty int
  ,itemDescription varchar(250)
  ,lineItem int
  ,maxAllowedInBox int
  ,itemsInBox int
  ,totalBoxesShipped int
)

Insert Into Testing Values
('123', 50, 'shirt', 1, 21, 0, 3)
,('123', 50, 'socks', 2, 21, 0, 3)
,('123', 50, 'hat', 3, 21, 0, 3)
```

Update the value of `itemsInBox` to `21, 21, 8` because 21+21+8 = 50 (the max allowed)
This is just a subset of data, but it illustrates what I am needing to do.  How can I write a SQL Server query to handle this?

I tried this `update` query, but it inaccurately updates because it's not accounting for everything as I need. :(

```
Update Testing
Set itemsInBox = 
case
      when [maxAllowedInBox] < totalQty then [maxAllowedInBox] 
      else [totalQty]-[maxAllowedInBox] 
end
```

Comment: You need to explain the logic also . How do you determine the 3 numbers `21 21 8` and any other combination like  `48 1 1` ?

Comment: @Squirrel - the logic is the max allowed in `1` box is 21, and we know there is a total of `3` boxes.  So `box 1` contains `21`, `box 2` contains `21` and `box 3` contains `50-21-21` - does that make sense?  A box can not contain any more than the `max`

Comment: So the required logic is to fill it up in ascending order of LineItem ?

Comment: But you only have a single row per line item? It seems you need another table of records to store how many items per box? Your order has 150 items, which are split across 3 line items, but split over 9 boxes? There isn't 9 records to store that data in?

Comment: @Squirrel - yes exactly!

Comment: @DaleK - it would seem it is 150 items, but it's only 50.  The 50 applies to all 3 line items and is duplicated for each row.  That is what I was meaning database structure is very very poor

Comment: In that case you'll need a window function or similar to calculate the amounts, probably using an updatable CTE.

Comment: And I suggest updating your question clarifying the information you've provided in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `sum()` with window function to get cumulative total and allocate to maxAllowedInBox to all lines except the last one

```
update t
set    itemsInBox = case when cumTotal <= totalQty 
                         then maxAllowedInBox
                         else totalQty - cumTotal + maxAllowedInBox
                         end
from
(
    select *, 
           cumTotal = sum(maxAllowedInBox) over (partition by saleId 
                                                     order by lineItem)
    from   Testing
) t
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=24b941378097d25c0f27c70e8530c133)